# String Concatenation appends Junk Characters with ctypes

Tags: python, string, ctypes, string-concatenation

I am appending "00000000" to a string and it works fine for the first time. However, when run second time "Junk Characters" are appended instead of "000000". This is the sample code how I am doing it in the actual program.

File one.py

```
# File One.py
from two import *

def One():
    while(1):
        key = Two()
        key = key + "00000000"
        print key

def main():
    One()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

File two.py

```
from ctypes import *
import binascii

handle = None

def Two():
    global handle
    libc = CDLL('libthree.so', DEFAULT_MODE, handle) 
    if not handle: 
        handle = libc._handle

    buffer = create_string_buffer(16)
    libc.Three(buffer)
    return binascii.b2a_hex(buffer)
```

File three.c - Generates libthree.so

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void Three(char * buffer)
{
    long value = 0x78563412;
    memcpy(buffer,&value,4);
    memcpy(buffer + 4,&value,4);
    memcpy(buffer+ 8,&value,4);
    memcpy(buffer+ 12,&value,4);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't b2a_hex take a number, not a char buffer?

Comment: I tested the code above, which worked perfectly; I couldn't reproduce your problem. You're going to have to explain more, or post the actual code you're using.

Comment: You should remove the definition of `main` from `three.c`—shared libraries don't have a main entry point like executables do.  Also, you should rename your local variable in the function `Two` from `libc` to `libthree`: `libc` means something completely different (the C runtime library) and should not be conflated with your library.

Comment: b2a_hex(data) takes binary data as input and returns hexadecimal representation of the data.

Answer (score 1):

`create_string_buffer` can be initialized with a string or a length.  If initialized with a string `s`, it allocates space for `len(s)+1` chars, so that the terminating null can be appended.  But if initialized with an integer value, `create_string_buffer` assumes that since you are the human, you must know what you are doing, and allocates just that much space.  Unfortunately, your C code is writing into the full 16 characters of space, so there is no room for a null terminator.  When this works for you, it is purely by accident that the byte after the allocated storage happens to be 0 (null), terminating the string. Later on, that memory gets used for something else, and then you get the garbage.  Try using `create_string_buffer(16+1)` instead, and see if things improve for you.

The docs also suggest using the `.string()` method of the returned string buffer object, so that you explicitly apply null-terminated semantics - the alternative is `.raw()` which will read past nulls up to the defined buffer size.  Ironically, if you specify `key = key.raw() + "000000"`, this may give you exactly the 16-character sized buffer you originally specified, and bypass the junk characters that way.

So here are two things you can try:

In One, do:

```
key = key.raw() + "00000000"
```

Or in Two, change to:

```
buffer = create_string_buffer(16+1)
```

But please don't do both.

Comment: When binascii.b2a_hex(buffer) is returned to "def One", the actual return value should be another string = key. So appending "00000000" to key, shouldn't pose any issues right ? I understand that, appending anything to buffer would cause overflow.

Comment: binascii.b2a_hex(data)
Return the hexadecimal representation of the binary data. Every byte of data is converted into the corresponding 2-digit hex representation. The resulting string is therefore twice as long as the length of data.
When I tried deepcopy in "def One", still I got the same issue. However, I am not facing any issues with the sample code in this thread.

Comment: Ah, then try `b2a_hex(buffer.raw())`.

Comment: None of the above changes were required. It was very very strange to see that when "def One" is called second time, the constant string "00000000" itself was getting corrupted. I tried to keep this string as a constant, a class variable but nothing helped. In all the scenarios, the string was getting corruped after first usage. If the length of the string is less that 8 ( 1 to 7 ) the string was not corrupted. Finally key = key + "0000" + "0000" did the trick.

Comment: Does "00000000" have any special significance in Python ? I am using version 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  4 2009, 17:46:50)